# How to initialize a variable with a line from a bidimensional array in C?

Tags: c

can somebody help me with this problem: I have a line i, an unidimensional array p and a bidimensional array(matrix) Q.
So, the problem is that I must initialize the unidimensional array p with the line i from Q without using a for-loop. How can I do that?

```
    void simVarDiscr(int m, int *x, double *p){//m is the number of elements of x and p
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        x[i]=i;
        init_genrand(254);//is a function from Mersenne-Twister algorithm
        p[i]=genrand_int32()%m;
    }
}
int LantMarkov(int m,double *pi0,float **Q){
    int *s,k,j;double *p;
    s=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    p=(double *)calloc(m,sizeof(double));
    simVarDiscr(m,s,pi0);
    j=s[0];
    for(k=0;k<n;k++){
        memcpy(p, Q[j], m);
        simVarDiscr(m,s,p);
        j=s[k];
    }
```

Comment: `memcpy(p, Q[i], size);` - well, `memcpy` will use a loop, so ...

Comment: Huh?? How about showing some code/data structure declarations, etc?  Go read this, and come back - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Ah, no. You have different types, a `float**` and a `double*`. Then `memcpy` won't work. You need an explicit loop.

Comment: @OldProgrammer For future reference: you can type `[ask]` in a comment to get this: [ask] :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on interpretation of your question: "initialize the unidimensional array p with the line i from Q without using a for-loop" - because your code doesn't initialize `p` with a line from `Q` using a `for` loop.

- A `for` loop can be replaced by a `while` loop or even a recursion.
- If you change the type of either `p` or `Q` so they are compatible (e.g. both `float`), you can use `memcpy` to copy from `Q` to `p`; I am not sure this helps you because you already have some `memcpy` (which has 2 bugs, so doesn't work) in your code.
- You can remove memory allocation for `p`, and have it point to a row in `Q`; this doesn't require a loop. For example:

-

```
void simVarDiscr(int m, int *x, float *p) // changed from double to float
{
    ... // No change in code
}

int LantMarkov(int m,double *pi0,float **Q)
{
    ...
    for(k=0;k<n;k++){
        p = Q[j];
        // The following code changes p and j'th row of Q in the same manner
        ...
    }
}
```